# I can't see any versions in the Rights and Pricing section of the Manage Your Apps module on iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Users who have already purchased your app are now able to download previous versions, allowing them to use your app with older devices that may no longer be supported by the current version.
If you do not want previous versions of your app to be available, for example due to a usability or legal issue, you can manage their availability in the Rights and Pricing section of the Manage Your Apps module on iTunes Connect.
For more information, refer to the iTunes Connect Developer Guide or contact us.
Regards,
The App Store team

**I can't see any versions in the Rights and Pricing section of the Manage Your Apps module on iTunes Connect,so how should i do.**

Comment: You are totally correct - for me and all our clients it is the same.  The spam email from Apple says we can control it in the "Rights and Pricing section" -- but I can see nothing there?

Comment: @user2848635 if I answered your question, please click "accept answer".

Answer (score 5):

You can find your app versions when you click on "**Manage iCloud download settings for this app**" at the **bottom** of the **Rights and Pricing** page.

Comment: The title of that section has changed but it is still the right place to go to view/manage past versions.